# Passing multiple value parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an existing stored procedure which accepts two single valued parameter. Now i have requirement to change one of its parameters to accept multiple values . I modified the stored procedure as below.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSpecificationsM1]
@EntityType   NVARCHAR(100)
,@EntityId BIGINT

    AS


    DECLARE @EntityTypeId AS BIGINT


    SET @EntityTypeId=ISNULL((SELECT ID 
                     FROM [ObjectTypes] WHERE [Type]=@EntityType),0)



    SELECT ISNULL([Specifications].[Id],0) AS [SpecificationId]
   ,ISNULL([Specifications].[Measure],'') AS [Measure]
   ,ISNULL([Specifications].[Notes],'') AS [Notes]
   ,ISNULL([UOM].[UOM],'') As UOM
   ,ISNULL(SpecificationsTemplate.Name,'') As Specification
   ,ISNULL(SpecificationsTemplate.Id, 0) AS SpecificationTemplateId
   ,ISNULL(Specifications.EntityId, 0) AS EntityId 
   ,(CASE WHEN ISNULL([SpecificationsTemplate].FieldTypeId,0)=0
   THEN 8 ELSE [SpecificationsTemplate].FieldTypeId END) AS [FieldTypeId]
    ,ISNULL(SpecificationsTemplate.ListId,0) AS ListId
    ,ISNULL([Specifications].[ListItemId],0) AS [ListItemId]
  FROM [SpecificationsTemplate] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Specifications] 
   ON [SpecificationsTemplate].[Id]=[Specifications].[SpecificationTemplateId]

    AND [Specifications].[EntityTypeId]=@EntityTypeId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [UOM] ON  [SpecificationsTemplate].[UOMId]=[UOM].[Id]
   WHERE   [Specifications].[EntityId] IN (@EntityId) 

   GO
```

In the above code I modified @EntityId to accept multiple values in the last line of the code. But I am getting an error as cannot convert Varchar to BigINt when i try to pass multiple values into the parameter as @EntityId=9,10,11.

Kindly help me out with the solution.

Thanks !

Comment: The parameter need to be a single value.Why are you passing 9,10,11.According to me the problem is here.Show us how you are calling the stored procedure.

Comment: Can you change your program to loop data to parameter?

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn I am using this stored procedure in my SSRS report. I need the stored procedure to return values for multiple entity IDs. I have created a parameter in my SSRS report which allows multple value and I have passed that parameter to this Stored procedure.

Comment: @vasin1987 How do I do that ? Sorry I am new to stored procedures.

Comment: @user1699025 You can pass the values as XML and parse xml parameter in Stored Procedure. Or else pass as text with some separation characters (You already doing it using ',') and write a sql function to split the values.

Comment: this was helpful for me: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/passing-multivalued-variables-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stored procedure change the parameter where condition something like below

Eg:

```
WHERE ([CostCentre]) collate database_default IN(SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@CostCentre,','))
```

Complete code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeSP] 
   @CostCentre NVARCHAR(255)
AS 
   SELECT
      [ProjectCode],[ProjectName], [ProjectManager],SUM([Hours]) AS [Hours MTD]
   FROM dbo.Rpt_NRMA_CATS NC
   INNER JOIN PeriodID P ON NC.PeriodID = P.PeriodID
   WHERE 
      ([CostCentre]) collate database_default IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@CostCentre, ','))
```

Comment: I am getting an error as 
Expression type bigint is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your where condition to

```
WHERE [Specifications].[EntityId] IN (select item from dbo.fnSplit(@EntityId))
```

The code for fnSplit function is [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/AngelEyes/archive/2007/04/12/111504.aspx)